# Long setTimeout in NodeJS on Raspberry PI

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I have a weird issue where long setTimeouts don't trigger on Raspberry PI, but they do on Ubuntu/x64 and OSX.

```
'use strict';

const delay = 1000 * 3600 * 8;
const date = new Date();

date.setTime(new Date().getTime() + delay);
console.log('Alarm set to', date.toString());

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Alarm!', new Date());
}, delay);
```

This code will echo `Alarm!` after 8 hours on Ubuntu/x64, but it never triggers on RPI.

Works:

- Ubuntu/x64
- OSX

Doesn't work:

- RPI b+ with Raspian 7 (Node 6.1)
- RPI 3 with Raspian 8 (Node 4.4.4, 6.0 and 6.1)

According to `ps` the script is in `Sl` state: `Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete), is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do).`

In a more complex version of this code, where I can control the script through a Web UI, the "alarm" will go off after the set time, but only when I access the Web UI (to wake up the application?).

Is this a NodeJS bug or am I doing something funky?

Comment: Found this, seems to be an known issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4262

Comment: I experienced the same. This issue is still outstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this solves it, until the NodeJS issue is fixed.

```
// Every 20 min to keep awake
setInterval(() => 1, 1000 * 60 * 20);
```